# Distance Between 2 Zip Code Columns Error

Tags: r, zipcode

I'm using the zip_distance() function from the zipcodeR package and am running into some issues. I have two columns pictured below:

[image]

Both columns are formatted as characters. I am attempting to run the following code:

```
Data$Distance_Travelled_Miles <- zip_distance(Data$Zip_Code,Data$OppZip_Code)
```

When I do I get the following error:
Warning messages:

```
1: In .data$zipcode == zipcode_a :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In .data$zipcode == zipcode_b :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I've checked the length of both columns and everything seems ok. Any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: Please edit your question and share your data using `dput(YourData)` or `dput(head(YourData))`. Posting data as an image makes it hard to answer your question.

Comment: It seems to me, that `zip_distance` is not vectorized. Therefore you have to use it in a `for`-loop or an `apply`-function

Comment: Try: `Data$Distance_Travelled_Miles <- sapply(seq_along(df$Zip_Code), function(n) zip_distance(df$Zip_Code[n], df$OppZip_Code[n]))`.